# Career in Game or in Software/Web

Tags: game-industry

I am Currently Working in GameLoft India ..I have also great skills in Web Development and Software Development I had learned J2EE , Sliverlight , Asp.
Now I am confused about my career

1)should i continue as a game programmer.
2)Should i try in Adobe, MS , Google.
3)If i continue my career in game field what's the my future.What's thing i need to improve for getting great job in Game field.

Plz reply i am very serious about this

Comment: This question is too subjective. It totally depends on your personal career objectives. Also, you have not explained what exactly the cause of confusion. I suspect you need to think in the direction that fixes that first.

Comment: Confusion is that I wants job in Adobe,MS,Apple but i think i can't achieve this by gaming experience.

Comment: As Jake says, this question is entirely subjective. What do you enjoy doing? are you after a job doing what you love or a job you're paid a lot for? Take a look at this answer http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/career-in-game-development?rq=1

Comment: Just FYI, not many companies will take you seriously when you say something like "Plz reply i am very serious about this". Work on your grammar and punctuation. I suggest not using "plz", it comes across as immature. Good luck in your career!

Comment: ya you are Correct Byte56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to be an Indie game developer :

Let's be straight about one thing, Game Development, Indie if you mean, is hard nut to crack.

If you want to be a game developer having a wide spectrum of skill isn't enough. You need to be persistent and focused about what you do. Test yourself. Make a simple game. For the sake of making things easy, take one existing 2d game you like and replicate it with minor changes. You will get an overall idea of what it takes. Your previous experience will help you to get started.

Regarding your last questions, there is a lot of things you can do to get a job in game industry, in case of big titles. The question is what part of game development are you interested in.

If you are unsure about what to do, and you currently have a job, stick with that and make a game that 'you'd like to make' in your spare time. You will know, if your fit for it.